# List<SkuDetails> to json gives incomplete json list

Tags: java, android

I receive a `List<SkuDetails>` as following:

```
public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(skuDetailsList);
    Log.d(TAG, json);
```

[SkuDetails doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails)

Then I get this unfinished json:

```
[{"zza":"{\"skuDetailsToken\":\"s-r3R-r\",\"productId\":\"chill_lo_fi\",\"type\":\"inapp\",\"price\":\"R$ 5,49\",\"price_amount_micros\":5490000,\"price_currency_code\":\"BRL\",\"title\":\"Chill Lo-Fi (SDoubleKick - Footdrum - SS)\",\"description\":\"Chill Lo-Fi sound pack\"}","zzb":{"nameValuePairs":{"skuDetailsToken":"s-r3R-r","productId":"chill_lo_fi","type":"inapp","price":"R$ 5,49","price_amount_micros":5490000,"price_currency_code":"BRL","title":"Chill Lo-Fi (SDoubleKick - Footdrum - SS)","description":"Chill Lo-Fi sound pack"}}},{"zza":"{\"skuDetailsToken\":\"a-r\",\"productId\":\"percussion_and_fx\",\"type\":\"inapp\",\"price\":\"R$ 5,49\",\"price_amount_micros\":5490000,\"price_currency_code\":\"BRL\",\"title\":\"Percussion and Fx (SDoubleKick - Footdrum - SS)\",\"description\":\"Percussion and Fx sound pack\"}","zzb":{"nameValuePairs":{"skuDetailsToken":"s-dsf3
```

You can see that this is a list, it should have printed correctly, but I get, in the end:

```
"zzb":{"nameValuePairs":{"skuDetailsToken":"s-dsf3
```

Because of that, when I reconstruct this gson into an object, I get an exception

Comment: Are you certain that your `json` String is actually truncated? It's possible that the logger just has a limit on how much it will print for a single log line.

Answer (score 1):

`Gson` will not truncate your JSON data. `logcat` is the culprit here, by default, it will truncate any log message that it considers to be too long. This can happen both inside of your IDE and when running `logcat` on the command line. To get rid of the log capping you can  split the string you want to log with creating a wrapper something like this:

```
package com.github.fundamentals.array;

public class Log {

  public static void d(String tag, String jsonText) {
    int maxLogSize = 2000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonText.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
      int start = i * maxLogSize;
      int end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
      end = end > jsonText.length() ? jsonText.length() : end;
      android.util.Log.d(tag, jsonText.substring(start, end));
    }
  }

}
```

You can also use `setPrettyPrinting` on `GsonBuilder` to print a JSON string in a human-readable format (for debugging)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String prettyJson = gson.toJson(json);
Log.d(TAG, prettyJson);
```

Comment: I don't want it to pretty print, I just want it to be displayed entirely. It's missing some parts.

Comment: I thought it was not showing the entire json because of some bug, but it's actually because of Log.d limit?

Comment: @Guerlando OCs, yeah logcat starts capping the log messages if the length of message is more than 1000 characters.